# Efficient way for very long intervals in Java

Tags: java, performance, wait, intervals

I am writing a program for school which will send an E-Mail if something changes on to school time table. Program will have to read updated information every 5 minutes from school's website until 4:00 PM and will have to wait for next 14 hours and repeat the same.

My question is: How do I implement this short ~5 min and the very long ~14h intervals efficiently in Java?

Just use Thread.wait(millis)?

Thanks!

//edit: Thanks for the answers, I think I will use a once executed Timer and will calculate the new delay after every update.

Comment: Checking every 5 mins uses very little processing power and teachers often have work after 4 PM ;)  I would just check every 5 Mins.

Comment: I'd use the executor framework for both... That is far cleaner to use than to do all these things by hand. (And Peter Lawrey is right, as there is nothing to do, I wouldn't care for the job running on 5 minute intervals at night too.)

Comment: It's also worth nothing that you could be saving CPU at the time when it is least in demand.

Comment: Of course it matters. The CPU won't care about it, but on a weekend you would perform about 800 useless calls, which would waste a lot of energy!

Answer (score 1):

Even if the performance doesn't really matter in this case, just check the current date with `Calendar.getInstance()` or `new Date()` before you initiate the check of the website. If it's not in your time-frame, do nothing. For scheduling the website-check, just use a `java.util.Timer` or similar services/frameworks.

Comment: +1 I would use ScheduleExecutorService, but agree that you could check the hour of the day every five minutes and not do the check for certain hours or weekends.

Answer (score 0):

You could use schedule method of Java Timer. Everytime after executing the task, you should calculate an interval (based on current time) and schedule the task accordingly to new interval.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/). It meets most of timing/scheduling needs.